# SQL Pull apart a string at specific points (based off static text strings)

Tags: sql, string, substring

I have a string returning with some static text to denote where the next element will be displayed.  It's basically a concatenated field made of a bunch of label+text values that had no other place to live in the schema in this database.

The output would look like

> Product: productname Company: productcompany Type: producttype Site: productsite

Any of these could be blanks, but the "labels" of Product:/Company:/Type:/Site: will always exist.  I'd like to rip apart the string so I can create columns with each.

I can do substrings on here I believe, but I haven't had any success pulling apart the string correctly.

Some things I've tried with no success!

```
select 
impl_nm,
instr(impl_nm, 'Product:', 1,1)+1 as Start,
instr(impl_nm, 'Company:', 1, 2) as End
--substr(val, instr(impl_nm, 'Product: ', 1,1) + 1, decode(instr(impl_nm, 'Company:',1,2),0,length(impl_nm)+1,instr(impl_nm, 'Company:',1,2) ) - instr(impl_nm, 'Product: ', 1,1)-1 )    
from products
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: its a PDA (Netezza environment, IBM pure data analytics)  I'm pretty sure I've been writing most of my queries against it using oracle functions w/o an issue so far

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar with string manipulation - to redirect a subscription at generation time.

Having decided not to drop the entire scan through by flags - the basic solution is:

```
    Select right(left(impl_nm,Charindex( 'Company:',impl_nm, 1)-1),len(charindex( 'Company:',impl_nm, 1))-Charindex(left(impl_nm,Charindex('Company:',impl_nm, 1)), 'Product:',1)  +len('Product:')+1)
,left(impl_nm,Charindex( 'Company:',impl_nm, 1)-1)
from (select 'Product: Sometext Company: somemoretext' impl_nm) c
```

Basically Truncate the string down to the end of the next field Name "Company" and then take the rightmost part corresponding to the length of the field.

Comment: you'll need to pay a little attention to how many characters you add/subract. this example actually includes the ": " (colon and space) so I should push forwards slightly.